# Creating a runtime visualization with CartoDb

Tags: carto, cartocss, carto-js

I am trying to create a runtime visualization for a CartoDB map and I am quite the trouble with doing it. I have gone over the documentation and cannot get the code to work correctly at all unless it is a static vis. We are wanting to use the runtime code because our data is ever updating and we want the map to update with the code. Here is what I have thus far.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />

<div id="map"></div>


<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>

<script>
function main() {
 cartodb.createLayer(map, {
  user_name: 'edwinorange',
  type: 'cartodb',
  sublayers: [{
    sql: "SELECT * FROM carto_db",
    cartocss: '#carto_db { marker-fill: red; }'
  }]
})
.addTo(map)
.done(function(layer) {
layer.createSublayer({
 sql: "SELECT * FROM carto_db",
 cartocss:'#carto_db {marker-fill: #F0F0F0;}'
});
layer.getSubLayer(0).setSQL("SELECT * FROM carto_db LIMIT 10");

});
}
window.onload = main;


</script>
```

After writing this code and following along with the cartoDB documentation I don't get an output in the browser or any JS errors in the console. My hope is that I can receive support on how to correctly write the code that will create a runtime visualization of a map from our dataset.

I am not sure if what I am wanting is possible or not. We can create a static visualization however, when using the cartodbJS I am having no luck on creating a carto map from scratch using the above code.

Comment: What specifically is wrong? Please check out these guidelines for posting a question! http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Hi, i edited the post to clarify what i am needing. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

CartoDB allows you to update your datasets via synced tables. [Here](http://blog.cartodb.com/synced-tables-create-real-time-maps-from-data-anywhere/) you will find a blog post on how to make real-time visualizations with synced tables. In relation to your code, you forget several things (the basemap, for example). I have created [a working example](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/234f8a4f9a68106fcf8919de2885536c), but as you pointed out it is a static map. But I believe it will help you to check what you missed.